# List in recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to in recycler-view create a list of events dependent on the day, week, month etc? I need a recycler-view with items divided by date and in every single item has some number of events. But how to create item that will match the number of events? For example: if I have only one event the item shows only one event, but if there is more item shows more.
Something like the attached picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMeX3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Recycler View nested inside another Recycler View. The outer adapter will populate items which have different date and inner adapter will populate inner recycler view with number of events in that date. Give it a try. If problem arises, comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested recyclerview,but keep in mind that you may encounter some layout laggy problem.There are many topics about recyclerview performance optimization.